# BLAS Level 2 band matrix-vector product multiple vectors

Tags: c++, c, vector, blas, intel-mkl

A routine in BLAS Level 2 for banded matrix vector product exists, both for general and symmetric cases (links for MKL implementation).

[cblas_?gbmv](https://software.intel.com/node/181e3c0c-e04a-4464-b87c-7e5d085f38a8#181E3C0C-E04A-4464-B87C-7E5D085F38A8)

[cblas_?sbmv](https://software.intel.com/node/9a02d0da-7aa4-4c5d-be91-78d4ce4a42e9#9A02D0DA-7AA4-4C5D-BE91-78D4CE4A42E9)

Is there any way to use multiple vectors (without using an outside for-loop), to maximize performance in such cases?

Comment: When you have a dense full matrix (more than one vector) there is no way to exploit the banded structure of one to gain speed.

Comment: @percusse I do not think your statement holds. Maybe you misunderstood my question. I want multiple right-hand side vectors, that is y=A*x where A is sparse banded and x is N-by-d. You can take advantage of each vector in x, since their results is independent (each column of y)

Comment: Yes that's why BLAS3 doesn't have them because it's just looping over every column of y hence BLAS2 functions. BLAS3 uses blocks not columns of RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the [Spike library](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/~polizzi/spike/index.htm) is supposed to have such a routine for the symmetric case. I'm afraid I cannot be of any more help, though, as I have never used it.

The algorithm and implementation of Spike (for system solving) is outlined in [[Polizzi & Sameh, Comp. Fluids (36), 2007]](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.compfluid.2005.07.005).

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct, over Picaud Vincent's, only because you provided a valid alternative. However, I do believe this is something that should be available in the BLAS implementations.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the answer is no.

The complete list of level3 BLAS subroutines can be found here

http://www.netlib.org/blas/#_level_3

and there is no banded-matrix subroutine.

---

**Extra information:** if you are using blas/lapack & C++ there is a recent initiative to design a C++ interface:

http://www.netlib.org/na-digest-html/17/v17n21.html#1

(cblas and lapacke are more oriented for a C usage)